# Android Studio Volley Library(BasicNetwork Error)

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio

I Followed some tutorials for connecting phpMyAdmin(WAMP) to my android studio. I Followed the tutorial well and still getting this error.
what am i doing wrong? I'm using my Device(Lollipop 5.0) and Android Studio 1.0.

```
10-07 00:27:03.719  25314-25616/com.example.galvez.php E/Volley﹕ [11353] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for http://192.16*.**.**/poi/showData.php
```

Heres my android code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


EditText POI,POILongLat,POIType,POIAddress,POIZipCode;
Button insertVal,showVal;
TextView textResult;
RequestQueue requestQueue;
String  insertUrl="http://192.168.**.**/poi/insertData.php";
String showUrl="http://192.168.**.**/poi/showData.php";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    POI = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPOI);
    POILongLat=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPOILongLat);
    POIType = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPOIType);
    POIAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPOIAddress);
    POIZipCode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPOIZipCode);
    insertVal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnInsert);
    showVal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnView);
    textResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResult);


    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

    showVal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                    showUrl,new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){


            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                try {
                    JSONArray pois = response.getJSONArray("stud");
                    for(int i=0;i<pois.length();i++){
                          JSONObject pointOfInterest = pois.getJSONObject(i);

                        String strPOI = pointOfInterest.getString("POI");
                        String strPOILongLat = pointOfInterest.getString("POILongLat");
                        String strPOIType = pointOfInterest.getString("POILongLat");
                        String strPOIAddress = pointOfInterest.getString("POIAddress");
                        String strPOIZipCode = pointOfInterest.getString("POIZipCode");
                        textResult.append(strPOI+" "+strPOILongLat+" "+strPOIType+" "+strPOIAddress+" "+strPOIZipCode);
                        Log.v("",strPOI+" "+strPOILongLat+" "+strPOIType+" "+strPOIAddress+" "+strPOIZipCode);
                    }
                    textResult.append("===\n");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

            requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

        }
     });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the error message:

```
Unexpected response code 403
```

and how you make the request:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new       JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                showUrl,new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
```

It's logical to jump to the conclusion that your server is creating a 403 forbidden response due to CSRF protection. You can confirm that this is indeed the case by looking at the webserver log file.

You have two choices, switch off CSRF protection for that url if you do not have any critical data or make a get request to the same url so that cookies are set properly.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. How can I switch off CSRF? Thanks!

Comment: In PHP it doesn't have built in CSRF support, your CSRF protection comes from your framework so you will have to refer to it. This is assuming of course that the log file confirmed my prediction of CSRF causing the 403 error.

Comment: I Really DOn't knw what to do. I Tried configuring my WAMP but still nothing happened. :'(

Comment: Did you look at the webserver log file? That is the first thing that you should have done

Comment: In the tutorial i followed, he is using XAMPP. I'll try to use xampp first. Hope this solved my problem :'( I'll come back here again if ever i get the same error. Thank you!

Comment: I Solved it using Xampp. Thanks for the Help! :) I Really Appreciate it.

Comment: I was wondering why my app keep getting 403 on a request, turn out if you omit `Method.GET` and add request parameters, JsonObjectRequest changes your method to POST which trigger CSRF error on my API server.